# How to Use and Image for a Mouse Pointer using Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a mouse cursor that uses an image instead of the default pointer.

I've created a class and set the cursor to point an image in my CSS;

```
/* CSS Basic Reset */
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

.mouse-pointer {
    cursor: url('/assets/images/cursor.png'), auto;
}
```

Then, I'm creating a logical division element with JavaScript, adding the `'mouse-pointer` class to it, and appending the `mousePointer` element to the `document.body`;

```
const mousePointer = document.createElement('div');
mousePointer.classList.add('mouse-pointer'); // Update to 'mouse-pointer'

document.body.appendChild(mousePointer);
```

I was expecting to see an image instead of the default mouse cursor, but I see nothing. I'm new to this, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not looking for solutions in JQuery, or anything else outside of vanilla JavaScript. I'm not looking to use CSS to accomplish this effect either.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see, you have the `pointer` only for the `div` added.  The `div` is `0px` high. And due to block-level-element `100%` of the parent `width`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was more simple than I expected. Here's my solution.

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'url(../assets/images/cursor.png), auto';
```

That being said, this isn't the solution I was hoping for because it's not a solution to the specific problem I was having. The problem I had is still present, I'm just using something different to accomplish something similar.

Comment: I was just writing the answer, but I am glad you managed to solve it.

Comment: that may not work with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change the mouse cursor globally across the entire webpage using `JavaScript` without altering the `CSS` for the whole `body` or `document` directly, you need to set the cursor style at a higher level, ideally on the body or html tag.

Here's how you could do it directly with JavaScript:

```
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("/assets/images/cursor.png"), auto';
```

Comment: What is the reason my code didn't work? Aside from maybe an incorrect path or something?

Comment: You mention that "The problem I had is still present, I'm just using something different to accomplish something similar." What is the problem that you're still facing?

Comment: The issue is that the pointer would default to the cursor within a specific distance of the edge of the view port, breaking the visual effect I was hoping to achieve.

After looking at other examples, I found a solution that I think is more effective and extensible for the effect I plan on implementing; a lazy movement of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I found the solution I was looking for.

First, I created a CSS class for `.mouse-pointer`, and set its `background-image` to the `.png` I wanted to use. I also set custom variables for the `width` and `height`; values that will be passed in later on in the script.

```
.mouse-pointer {
    background-image: url('/assets/images/cursor.png');
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Next, I created a new logical division and assigned the `className` of `'mouse-pointer'` to it;

```
const mousePointer = document.createElement('div');
mousePointer.className = 'mouse-pointer';
```

I then set up variables to pass in size and page position values;

```
let size = 50;
let pageX = 0;
let pageY = 0;
```

Next, I appended the `mousePointer` to the document of the body, and set custom variable size--`var(--size)`--properties;

```
document.body.appendChild(mousePointer);
mousePointer.style.setProperty('--size', size+'px');
```

Then to wrap everything up, I added an eventListener to the global window object to track the movement of the mouse (offsetting it by a few pixels);

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(mouseMovementDirection) {
    pageX = mouseMovementDirection.clientX;
    pageY = mouseMovementDirection.clientY;
    mousePointer.style.left = mouseMovementDirection.clientX-size/2+'px';
    mousePointer.style.top = mouseMovementDirection.clientY-size/2+'px';
  });
```

This achieves the desired effect I was looking for.

Here's the full code;

CSS:

```
/* CSS Basic Reset */
*, *::after, *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: none;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

.mouse-pointer {
    background-image: url('/assets/images/cursor.png');
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And the JavaScript;

```
const mousePointer = document.createElement('div');
mousePointer.className = 'mouse-pointer';

let size = 50;
let pageX = 0;
let pageY = 0;


document.body.appendChild(mousePointer);

mousePointer.style.setProperty('--size', size+'px');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(mouseMovementDirection) {
    pageX = mouseMovementDirection.clientX;
    pageY = mouseMovementDirection.clientY;
    mousePointer.style.left = mouseMovementDirection.clientX-size/2+'px';
    mousePointer.style.top = mouseMovementDirection.clientY-size/2+'px';
  });
```

Great! Now I'm up and running!

With that said, I hope the verbosity of my post isn't breaking any Stack rules, but I think a detailed explanation like this can help others down the road.